# Don't want to display constructor initialization in the jsp page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications

I am working on web application, where I used a class Calculator with following information:-

```
public class Calculator {
 private static String name,familyname;

public Calculator() {
    name = "Roberto";
    familyname = "Sanchez";
}


public static String getName() {
    return name;
}

public static String getFamilyname() {
    return familyname;
}}
```

In my index.jsp file, I used following code:-

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : login
    Created on : Nov 3, 2016, 6:21:46 AM
    Author     : yati
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Student Information</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#00FFFF">
        <%=new com.algeb.Calculator()%> <br>
        First Name: <%= com.algeb.Calculator.getName()%> <br>
        Family Name: <%= com.algeb.Calculator.getFamilyname()%> <br>
            <a href="login.jsp"> Check Result</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, my webpage looks like this:-
[image]

My problem is that I don't to display the first line (Calling class with the help of object) i.e. **com.algeb.Calculator@3490ac94**. This is also important step as without this, I cannot initialize the first name and last name. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use JSP beans:

```
<jsp:useBean id= "instanceName" scope= "page | request | session | application"   
class= "packageName.className"/>
```

And than use id to call getName() and getFamilyname() methods, for example:

```
${instanceName.getFamilyname()}
${instanceName.getFamilyname()}
```

Comment: This is acceptable but without javabeans, is it possible??

Comment: You can create an object in JSP eather as you did (new Object) or as I did (javabean).